# Symfony2 custom event dispatcher and listener

Tags: symfony, events

I am trying to create custom event, but can't make it work.

What I have done:

1.I created event identifying class in

```
namespace Path\ToBundle;  
final class CookieEvents
{
    const COOKIE_EVENT = 'cookie.event';
}
```

2.Created event

```
namespace Path\ToBundle\EventListener;
use Path\ToBundle\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
class ResponseListener
{
    public function onCookieInit(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        //some complex logic goes here
        echo('test');
    }
}
```

3.created event listener

```
namespace Path\ToBundle\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class FilterResponseEvent extends Event
{
    protected $response;
    public function __construct(Response $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

4.Tried to register event listener inside service.yml

```
kernel.listener.cookie.event:
    class: Path\ToBundle\Event\ResponseListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: cookie.event, method: onCookieInit }
```

5.Next I try to dispatch event inside controller action

```
//includes before class
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Path\ToBundle\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

//inside controller action
//... $response variable is created

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$event = new FilterResponseEvent($response);
$dispatcher->dispatch(CookieEvents::COOKIE_EVENT, $event);

return $response;
//EOF controller action
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able fire event on certain actions. Unfortunately this doesn't work.
The events concept is new to me and, I am still not confident in what I am doing here, but's it what I was able to figure out of the examples. Maybe someone could tell me if I'm going to right direction and correct me? If not, some guidance is even more appreciated.

Comment: For the dispatcher your should use `$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher')` as you will be using a different instance.

Comment: This is a great example of how to set up custom events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, @Qoop for pointing out correct usage of dispatcher:

```
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher')
```

Also, there was namespace error:

```
class: Path\ToBundle\Event\ResponseListener  //incorrect

class: Path\ToBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener  //correct
```